# RSpec / Rails - How do I test that a method in ApplicationController is called (when I'm testing a subclassed controller)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Title says it all.

I have a controller action in which I do some stuff, then call a method that is defined in `ApplicationController`.

How do I test that it was called?

`controller.should_receive(:the_method_name)` doesn't work.
`ApplicationController.should_receive(:the_method_name)` doesn't work.

What's the proper syntax?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for stubs? http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-mocks/frames

Comment: I don't think so.  I don't want to stub out the method; I want to test that it was called.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [anonymous controller](http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-4/dir/controller-specs/anonymous-controller) to test your ApplicationController, check the documentation.

Comment: The documentation describes how to stub methods on the anonymous controller, not the ApplicationController from which it inherits.

Answer (score 0):

Using the AnonymousController as Gerep suggested and calling `controller.should_receive(:the_method_name)` should do it.

The position within the test is important to let the test pass successfully. To give you an example:

```
describe 'my test' do
  before do
    controller.should_receive(:the_method)
    get :action
  end
  it { should render_template(:your_template) }
end
```

This example should pass and tests also the call of `:the_method`.

Comment: Can you expand on your first six words?

Comment: But `controller` then refers to the instance of the AnonymousController, and not the ApplicationController.